# google maps and modals

Tags: angularjs, google-maps, modal-dialog, angular-ui

I am trying to show google maps on modal.

is there any away I can load my modal first before my google maps?
I get an "Unable to get property 'offsetWidth' of undefined or null reference" because the 'div id="map"' is inside my ng-template script.

I know there is a ngmaps library but I don't wanna use it.

Comment: modal is usual div, so same code should work. Try creating plunk showing your problem.

Comment: Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/y4wgx/14/?